# Getting elevated permissions in code

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

A console-app runs on a server in a domain and is tasked with deleting some home areas of users, who are no longer active.

The account runs under the context of an account, that is also a member of the Local Administrator group on each storage server, which has "Full Control" access to the relevant folders.

This works great on a bunch of older servers, but on Windows 2008 it runs into problems. On these servers, "Admin Approval Mode" is enabled for the "Local Administrator" group.

For instance, if I right-click a folder and try to access properties/security (using the same service account), I get this prompt:

[image]

I can press continue, and then proceed to use the full control permissions. If I do the same when deleting files, things work like intended.

There are two potential solutions, as I see it:

1. The "Admin approval mode" is removed. This is not a viable option according to the security-people here.
2. The console-app can somehow do the code-equivalent of pressing "Continue" and proceeding.

Is option no. 2 possible? If so, what would that code look like - or what key concepts do I need to research further to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.

There is no solution to this BY DESIGN, so I am making this the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can set the app to be run as administrator. Right click on the app *exe* file, select *Properties*, *Compatibility* tab and check *Run this program as administrator* check box (the names of options can be different, my Windows is in another language).

If you want the app to request the elevated priviledges by itself, you can make modification in **manifest** file as described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105506/Getting-Elevated-Privileges-on-Demand-using-C. It should make the app request admin permissions (so the prompt for permissions should appear), but I suppose you have to still click the *Continue* button (that's how UAC works).

Also consider what *Alex* wrote in his answer, maybe you should just talk with IT guys to set permissions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, applications can't just "bypass" Windows's security.

I'd make IT setup a local "super-admin" account on the server in order to allow that particular user only to bypass all security measures in order to let scheduled applications to run without issues. That's what we did on our servers, those accounts are as locked as it gets BUT they have just enough privileges to let scheduled taks run without questions. I have no clue on the how-to (our IT department took care of that) but I assume IT guys will know what to do.